# How make UiView displayed on top?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have two UiViewControllers. I need to be UIView with UiButton and UISlider displayed on top.
Also i already read any topics about this...but it's not work.

Comment: Init `yourSubView` with a frame.  If you have errors that you can't fix, show them in your question.

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UIView *yourSubView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(0,320,30,30);
    UIView *yourSubView = [UIView alloc];
   [newView addSubView:yourSubView];
   [newView bringSubviewToFront:yourSubView];
    
    
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: I have error about method SubView not found,redefenision SubView and others.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have two UIViewControllers"? Is the view with the Play button and slider, the view of a different view controller than the one with the web view?

Comment: Okey i have two screen with table and WebView, i need make UiView(when button and slider) on the top this two screen. Understand?

Comment: Please don't describe errors; paste them into the question exactly as they appear.  Most of us are better at recognizing what Xcode says than we are at interpreting an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the quartzCore zPosition = MAXFLOAT

Just Like this:

```
yourView.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT
```

Comment: I Have error zPozition cannot be found in forward class CALayer...any idea?

Comment: have you included quartzcore framework and zPosition not zPozition

Comment: It's not work. I paste newView.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT; in my AppDelegate. BUT My UIView not show on the second viewcontroller

Comment: you should put yourSubview.layer.zPosition since its the one you want to be on top right

Comment: I must open ViewController.m in -(Void)ViewDidLoad paste this code, its true?

Comment: where did you put newView and yourSubView is it in the same ViewController or did you put it in the delegate? maybe you can show how you implemented them.